# Matching user sequence in awk

Tags: awk

I am matching line accarding to regexp pattern `beg_ere`.  A user can also pass
a comma separated sequence `ukeys` to match values in `pkeys` read from the matched
line in the file being processed.  If any elements in `ukeys` match elements in
`pkeys`, display is set to a value of 1 (`display = 1`).

My problem is that when elements in `kaggr` have leading or trailing spaces,
the condition `(uaggr[i] == kaggr[j])` fails.

```
match($0, beg_ere, paggr) {
  pkeys = paggr[4]
  nuk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",")
  npk = split(pkeys, kaggr, ",")

  if ( nuk == 0 ) {
      display = 1
   }
  else if ( nuk > 0 && npk > 0 ) {
     umatch = 0
     for (i in uaggr) {
        for (j in kaggr) {
           if (uaggr[i] == kaggr[j]) { umatch = 1 ; break }
         }
       if (umatch == 1) { display = 1 }
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `fieldsep` argument to the [`split` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function-1) can be a regular expression, so you can remove the whitespace while splitting

```
npk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",[[:blank:]]*")
```

demo

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    ukeys = "a, b, c"
    npk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",")
    for (i=1; i <= npk; i++) printf "%d\t>%s<\n", i, uaggr[i]
}'
1   >a<
2   > b<
3   > c<
```

but

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    ukeys = "a, b, c"
    npk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",[[:blank:]]*")
    for (i=1; i <= npk; i++) printf "%d\t>%s<\n", i, uaggr[i]
}'
1   >a<
2   >b<
3   >c<
```

---

Alternately, use [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1) to create a "trim" function:

```
awk '
    function trim(s) { gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "", s); return s }
    BEGIN {
        ukeys = "a, b, c"
        npk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",")
        for (i=1; i <= npk; i++) printf "%d\t>%s<\t>%s<\n", i, uaggr[i], trim(uaggr[i])
    }
'
1   >a<     >a<
2   > b<    >b<
3   > c<    >c<
```

Comment: The `",[[:blank:]]*"` approach fails for the first element where there can be preceding spaces.